# When multiple sources give the content of an ingredient my an unqualified percentage, can I safely assume this is by weight? Or; it's not a wart

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry, safety, units

I am trying to make a simple scented shampoo and body soap for my own use and for Christmas gifts.

I statr with a base of 32 oz – (a bit under a kg) of a mild commercial castille soap (Dr. Bronner’s Peppermint) to which I have added modest amounts of essential oils ranging from 2 tablespoons (lavender) to a few ml (jasmine  and pine needle) down to a few drops (vetiver, bergamot). Because I have dandruf on my head and psoriasis on my elbows, and because I know both of the other people I am gifting use cosmetics containing exfoliants, I decided to add one percent of salicylic acid to the shampoo. Over-the-counter cosmetics use up to 2 percent, and prescription shampoos are available with up to six percent. This seemed adequately cautious for a first-time emdevor, and assuming thee percentage was by weight, I added a bit under10 gm of powdered salicylic acid to the almost a kg of shampoo.

Here is my question: at least half of the salicylic acid has not gone into solution after considerable agitation. This make me wonder if I am not adding too much salicylic acid because I am measuring the percentage incorrectly. Should I be measuring the shampoo by dry weight? Or reconstituting the salicylic acid somehow before weighing it? Or defining the percentage in molar terms? Or should I be doing something else to encourage solubility (boil it?) or to make it into a suspension or something?

I was hoping to try it out, but I thought I should try to establish that I am not using way too much acid.  A 24 percent solution is sold as wart remover.  I clearly don’t want to apply that on my head.

Comment: Yes, weight percents should be assumed. Salicylic acid solubility depends on what you are dissolve it in.

Comment: Solubility of salicylic acid is strongly dependent on the pH. In pure water, the solubility is only  $1.8$ g/L at $20$°C. If totally neutralized by sodium, the solubility is huge : $1110$ g of sodium salicylate can be dissolved in $1$ L water. In hard water, the solubility is increased a bit, as calcium salicylate solubility is $27$ g/L. In your case I would recommend to add an equal amount of soda ($\ce{Na2CO3}$). This will improve the solubility of your salicylic acid.

Comment: @Maurice OTOH, alkaline pH is not desirable for shampoo, so it should be neutralized by the shampoo components.

Comment: @Poutnik. pH 8 should be sufficient to dissolve the given amount of salicylic acid.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice and @Poutnik! More of it dissolved overnight. I'll try just a couple of grams of soda and see if that does the job.

Comment: @Maurice Worked like a charm. If you'd make your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as such.

Comment: If you appreciate a comment you can express it by clicking on the small pale triangle which is in the margin before the comment. This will produce a number like 1 just before the triangle.